# Finding the column number of a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with column values 37, 35, 25, 24, 14, 12, 10, 2, 1.

I want to find the column number by using the Find() function.

It displays the column number of 37, 35, 25, 24, 14, 12 and 10 correctly.

Coming to 2, it finds the top most cell which contains 25 and is showing me that column number. Similarly 1 is giving me the value for 14.

```vb
For Each b In list3
    Set n = X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("A1:A" & CStr(lastRow)).Find(What:=b)
    MsgBox b
    name = CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("A" & CStr(n.Row)).Value) & ". " & CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("B" & CStr(n.Row)).Value) & " - " & CStr(X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master").Range("E" & CStr(n.Row)).Value)
    MsgBox name
Next b
```

Comment: Have a look to `WorksheetFunction.Match` instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match

Comment: `.Find(What:=b, Lookat:=xlWhole)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find()` has additional parameters which you should supply arguments for if you want full control over what it returns.  To avoid partial matches for example use `LookAt:=xlWhole`

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, B, f As Range, Name
    '...
    '...
    Set ws = X.Sheets("2023 Feedback Master")
    For Each B In list3
        Set f = ws.Range("A1:A" & CStr(lastRow)).Find(What:=B, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            With f.EntireRow
                Name = .Columns("A").Value & ". " & _
                       .Columns("B").Value & " - " & _
                       .Columns("C").Value
                MsgBox Name
            End With
        Else
            'not found...
        End If
    Next B
End Sub
```